# how to read data from csv file by using quick sort and display it

Tags: c++, visual-studio, csv, data-structures, read.csv

Can I know what is the best possible way to solve this issue, as I'm currently new to C++

The result that I expected was something like this

```
 id, title, price, date, mileage, fuel_type, transmission, engine_size, doors, colour, body_type, url, sale_date
```

```
3   ,Volkswagen Golf 1.9 TDI 11 Months MOT  ,650    ,2000   ,155822 Diesel  ,Manual ,1.9    ,4  ,Silver ,Hatchback  ,https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/124907646705?hash=item1d15136ef1:g:8dsAAOSwb-thRawR  ,25 Sep 2021
4   ,1999 Volkswagen Golf GTi 1.8 turbo AUM engine V20  British racing green 3 door     ,650    ,1999   ,178000 ,Petrol ,Manual ,1.8    ,3  ,Green  ,Hatchback  ,https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/114998243091?hash=item1ac66def13:g:7y4AAOSwSEdhL~1m  ,25 Sep 2021
```

But the result I got is like this

```
3.  - 0 - -858993460 - -858993460 -  -  -  - -858993460 -  -  -  -
4.  - 1999 - 0 - -858993460 -  -  -  - -858993460 -  -  -  -
5.  - 0 - 0 - -858993460 -  -  -  - -858993460 -  -  -  -
6.  - 5 - 0 - -858993460 -  -  -  - -858993460 -  -  -  -
```

I have tried a lot of different way to do it, but I'm still struggling to find a way to print all the input from the csv file properly. As it can read according to the id, yet it can't print all the data from the row specifically.

This is my code

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    #include <fstream>
    #include <sstream>
    using namespace std;
    
    int sizeofLinkedList = 0;
    struct Car
    {
    
        int id;
        string title, fuel_type, transmission, engine_size,  colour, body_type, url, sale_date;
        int price;
        int year;
        int mileage;
        int doors;
    
        Car* nextAddress;
        Car* prevAddress;
    } *head, * tail;
    
    Car* CreateNewNnode(int id, string title, int price, int year, int mileage ,string fuel_type, string transmission,
        string engine_size, int doors, string colour, string body_type, string url, string sale_date) //create a newnode - use for any insert
    {
    
    
        Car* newnode = new Car;
        newnode->id = id;
        newnode->title = title;
        newnode->price = price;
        newnode->year = year;
        newnode->mileage = mileage;
        newnode->fuel_type = fuel_type;
        newnode->transmission = transmission;
        newnode->engine_size = engine_size;
        newnode->doors = doors;
        newnode->colour = colour;
        newnode->body_type = body_type;
        newnode->url = url;
        newnode->sale_date = sale_date;
        newnode->nextAddress = NULL;
        newnode->prevAddress = NULL;
        return newnode;
    }
    
    Car* partition(Car* head, Car* end, Car** newHead, Car** newEnd)
    {
        Car* pivot = end;
        Car* prev = NULL, * cur = head, * tail = pivot;
    
        while (cur != pivot)
        {
    
            if (cur->id < pivot->id)
            {
                if ((*newHead) == NULL)
                    (*newHead) = cur;
    
                prev = cur;
                cur = cur->nextAddress;
            }
            else
            {
                if (prev)
                    prev->nextAddress = cur->nextAddress;
    
                Car* tmp = cur->nextAddress;
                cur->nextAddress = NULL;
                tail->nextAddress = cur;
                tail = cur;
                cur = tmp;
            }
        }
    
        if ((*newHead) == NULL)
            (*newHead) = pivot;
    
        (*newEnd) = tail;
    
        return pivot;
    }
    
    
    
    Car* getTail(Car* cur)
    {
        while (cur != NULL && cur->nextAddress != NULL)
            cur = cur->nextAddress;
    
        return cur;
    }
    
    Car* quickSortRecur(Car* head, Car* end)
    {
        if (!head || head == end)
            return head;
    
        Car* newHead = NULL, * newEnd = NULL;
        Car* pivot = partition(head, end, &newHead, &newEnd);
    
        if (newHead != pivot)
        {
            Car* tmp = newHead;
            while (tmp->nextAddress != pivot)
                tmp = tmp->nextAddress;
    
            tmp->nextAddress = NULL;
            newHead = quickSortRecur(newHead, tmp);
            tmp = getTail(newHead);
            tmp->nextAddress = pivot;
        }
    
        pivot->nextAddress = quickSortRecur(pivot->nextAddress, newEnd);
    
        return newHead;
    }
    
    void quickSort(Car** headRef)
    {
        (*headRef) = quickSortRecur(*headRef, getTail(*headRef));
    }
    
    // Modified insertIntoASortedList to use quicksort
    void insertIntoASortedList(Car* newnode)
    {
        // Insert new node at the end of the list
        if (head == NULL)
        {
            head = tail = newnode;
        }
        else
        {
            tail->nextAddress = newnode;
            newnode->prevAddress = tail;
            tail = newnode;
        }
    
        // Sort the list using quicksort
        quickSort(&head);
    }
    
    void readCsvFile() {
        ifstream file("carlist(1).csv");
        string line;
        int id;
        string title, fuel_type, transmission, engine_size, colour, body_type, url, sale_date;
        int price;
        int year;
        int mileage;
        int doors;
    
        while (getline(file, line)) {
            stringstream ss(line);
            int id;
            string title, fuel_type, transmission, engine_size, colour, body_type, url, sale_date;
            int price;
            int year;
            int mileage;
            int doors;
    
            ss >> id;
            getline(ss, title, ',');
            ss >> price;
            ss >> year;
            ss >> mileage;
            getline(ss, fuel_type, ',');
            getline(ss, transmission, ',');
            getline(ss, engine_size, ',');
            ss >> doors;
            getline(ss, colour, ',');
            getline(ss, body_type, ',');
            getline(ss, url, ',');
            getline(ss, sale_date, ',');
    
    
            Car* newnode = CreateNewNnode(id, title, price, year, mileage, fuel_type, transmission, 
                engine_size, doors, colour, body_type, url, sale_date);
            insertIntoASortedList(newnode);
        }
    }
    
    
    
    void SearchBasedOnPrice(int price1, int price2)
    {
        Car* current = head;
    
        while (current != NULL)
        {
            if (current->id >= price1 && current->id <= price2)
            {
                cout << current->id << ". " << current->title << " - " << current->price << " - "
                    << current->year << " - " << current->mileage << " - " << current->fuel_type << " - "
                    << current->transmission << " - " << current->engine_size << " - " << current->doors << " - "
                    << current->colour << " - " << current->body_type << " - " << current->url << " - "
                    << current->sale_date << endl;
            }
            current = current->nextAddress;
        }
        cout << "List ended here!" << endl;
    }
    
    int main()
    {
        head = NULL;
    
        srand(time(0));
        int noOfcar, choice = 1;
        int CarID, Year;
        string Brand, Type, color;
        int p1;
        int p2;
    
        cout << "Enter your searching p1: ";
        cin >> p1;
        cout << "Enter your searching p2: ";
    
        cin >> p2;
        readCsvFile();
        SearchBasedOnPrice(p1, p2);
    
    
        cout << endl;
        int answer; string word;
        cout << "Do you want to search anything from the list or not? 1 - Yes, 0 - No: ";
        cin >> answer;
        cin.ignore();
    
    
        while (answer == 1)
        {
    
    
            cout << "Enter your searching p1: ";
            cin >> p1;
            cout << "Enter your searching p2: ";
    
            cin >> p2;
            readCsvFile();
            SearchBasedOnPrice(p1, p2);
    
            cout << "Do you want to edit anything? 1 - Yes, 0 - No: ";
            cin >> answer;
    
            int CarID;
            if (answer == 1)
            {
                cout << "Enter your car ID: ";
                cin >> CarID;
                
            }
    
            cout << "Do you still want to search anything from the list or not? 1 - Yes, 0 - No: ";
            cin >> answer;
            cin.ignore();
            system("pause");
            system("cls");
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: `-858993460` == `0xCCCCCCCC`.  That's an uninitialized variable (on some systems/settings).  Your `readCsvFile()` function does not check if most of your file operations have failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is incorrect

```
        ss >> id;
        getline(ss, title, ',');
        ss >> price;
        ss >> year;
        ss >> mileage;
```

Think about this format `id,title,price,year,mileage etc`. There are four commas there but the above code only reads one comma, so it cannot be right.

Here's some code that should work better

```
        string tmp;
        getline(ss, tmp, ',');
        id = stoi(tmp);
        getline(ss, title, ',');
        getline(ss, tmp, ',');
        price = stoi(tmp);
        getline(ss, tmp, ',');
        year = stoi(tmp);
        getline(ss, tmp, ',');
        mileage = stoi(tmp);
```

This code reads all the commas, but where an integer is required it reads the data into a string `tmp` and then uses `stoi` to convert the string into an integer.

Comment: when i only use "getline(ss, tmp, ',');
        id = stoi(tmp);" it can run, but when i following the code above , there is be error message saying that abort() has been call, and i cant find why even though your code is correct

Comment: @MysteMyzte The abort will probably be because you have used `stoi` on a string that cannot be converted to an integer (because it's empty, or because it's non-numeric). Print out the value of the string before you call `stoi` and see what you get. This is debugging, it's a normal part of programming. Of course if you know how to use a *debugger* then that will make this easier.